# Change the button border when active nav tabs

Tags: css

I am using nav-tabs in with bootstrap panel.

On the panel header when the first button is active the border is thicker on left side and top.

> **Question:** What ever button is active how can I make sure it does not
>   show double thickness in border.

**[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wolfgang1983/4b5p2kaz/1/)**

[image]

```
.panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-justified{
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .panel-heading {
    background-color: #fafbfc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e4e8;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs > li > a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Default 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">Default 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">Default 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">Default 2</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the border set on the panel heading, combined with individual borders set on the tab (labels). You need to explicitly disable the borders on the tabs:

```
/*disable the top border on all tabs*/
.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs > li > a {
   border-top: none;
}

/*the first tab has an additional left border which is not needed
  since it can "take" the border of the header*/
.panel.with-nav-tabs .nav-tabs > li:first-of-type > a {
   border-left: none;
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjpghrtx/1/).

In case you'll have more tabs and they'll run up to the right side of the panel, you might add an additional rule for the "last-of-type" and take out the right border.

Comment: at the top left corner small gap border not touching on first button

Comment: fix had to add border-radius: 0; to panel-default

Comment: @wolfgang1983 the do touch but because of the border radius and the light grey border colour, it a bit hard to see.

Comment: Thanks for your help